# GPO Replication SysVol Inaccessible on Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, group-policy, replication

In our current AD setup, we have the following Domain Controllers:

- DC1: Server 2012 R2, Operations Master (All roles)
- DC2: Server 2012 R2
- Mailserver1: Server 2003, Also hosts Exchange 2007

The forest functional level is 2003.

However, no GPO's are beeing replicated to the mailserver. When checking the status of a GPO, it says `SysVol Inaccessible`

I've searched around on the web for any solution for this, but I cannot find anything. I'm fairly in the dark when it comes to Active Directory, so I have no clue where to go from here.

Anyone recognize this problem, or have some common causes? Any help would be tremendously appreciated.

**Update**

As requested, the output of NET SHARE on MAILSERVER1

```
Share name   Resource                        Remark

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IPC$                                         Remote IPC

C$           C:\                             Default share

ADMIN$       C:\WINDOWS                      Remote Admin

Resources$   C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\bin\res
                                             "Event logging files"

Address      C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\Mailbox\address
                                             "Access to address objects"

CertEnroll   C:\WINDOWS\system32\CertSrv\CertEnroll
                                             Certificate Services share

ExchangeOAB  C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\ExchangeOAB
                                             OAB Distribution share

NETLOGON     C:\WINDOWS\SYSVOL\sysvol\HQ.tarantech.com\SCRIPTS
                                             Logon server share

OAB          C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\ClientAccess\OAB

SYSVOL       C:\WINDOWS\SYSVOL\sysvol        Logon server share
```

Comment: Why would GPO's replicate to your Exchange server? Is the Exchange server also a Domain Controller? What is the Domain and Forest functional level?

Comment: @joeqwerty Yes, unfortunately the mailserver is also a DC. The forest functional level is 2003, I updated the question with it. Thanks for pointing the missing stuff out :)

Comment: On MAILSERVER1, what is the output of the NET SHARE command?

Comment: @GregAskew Updated the question with the output, thanks!

Comment: @ChristofferMansfield: Where are you seeing "SysVol Inaccessible"?  Is that on MAILSERVER1?  What are you running when that is displayed?

Comment: The NETLOGON and SYSVOL shares both exist on MAILSERVER1. Have you checked the contents of the SYSVOL directory on MAILSERVER1? I would also recommend that you compare the Share and NTFS permissions on the SYSVOL share on MAILSERVER1 to one of your other DC's.

Answer (score 1):

Group Policy processing is done as the user the relevant portion of the policy applies to.  If they cannot read the policy files, they cannot apply the policy.  Therefore, the users need to have read permissions to SYSVOL on the DC, and they also need to have SMB access to the DC so they can retrieve SysVol.

Once it finds the right server to use, the client (in this case, the mail server) does a Tree Connect Request Tree to \DC\IPC$ does a get to \domain\SysVol.  You can get a list of the DCs that you need SMB to by doing a nltest /dclist:.

As far as I can tell, that is the most probable issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem like this some time ago and it was caused by the FRS service in one DC being in JRNL_WRAP_ERROR. I discovered this after running DCDIAG and checking the eventlog if memory serves. If this were your case you could use the procedure in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315457 so fix it. Note that all my servers were running Windows Server 2003 SP2. Starting with Windows Server 2008 the replication is done by the DFS service so this could help http://support.microsoft.com/kb/292438 instead. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a invalid Journal Entry or something of the likes. All I had to do was set the reg value ´HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NtFrs\Parameters\Enable Journal Wrap Automatic Restore´ to 1 and wait five minutes.

Thanks to all of you who contributed :)

Comment: Can you edit to mention whether you did this on the PDC or on the affected DC?